# Building links in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to build and display a link in PHP with the code:

```
$displayLink = "<a href={$feed_url}{$feedName} download>$displayFeed</a>";
echo "<br />$displayLink";
```

This works fine, and I'm able to click the link in the HTML and follow it - unless $feedName contains a space.  Thus, 'shoes' works but 'our shoes' does not. With $fileName = 'shoes'  I get the link:

```
<a href="http://my_site/users/55/shirts.txt" download="">shoes</a>
```

which works fine.

With $fileName = 'our shoes' I get the link

```
<a href="http://my_site/users/55/shirts.txt" download="">our</a>
```

I've tried putting the $feedName  variable in single quotes, as below:

```
$displayLink = "<a href={$feed_url}{'$feedName'} download>$displayFeed</a>";
    echo "<br />$displayLink";
```

but that gives me the link:

```
href="http://my_site/users/55{'/our" shoes.txt'}="" download="">our shoes</a>
```

How can I get "our shoes" into the link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is actually just a problem with how you're constructing the anchor tag. Because you don't add quotes around the `href` value, a space would signify a break in the tag's value. Your browser would then move on at the space, and in the case of `our shirts`, shirts would become a new tag.

Just add quotes:

```
$displayLink = "<a href='{$feed_url}{$feedName}' download>$displayFeed</a>";
```

Example of the comparison: https://eval.in/574053